# MediaPlayer doesn't start video replay

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am allowing the user to take a video from his device :

```
private File video = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "my_file.mp4");
```

And now I want to replay it, so :

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(video.getPath());
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But the video never shows... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `VideoView` for playing the videos in your app.

```
private VideoView videoView;

videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.YOUR_WEBSITE_ADDRESS.com/your_video.mp4");
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override       
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       mp.setLooping(true);
       videoView.start();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.